# two laravel projects under the same domain name

Tags: php, laravel, session

I run two laravel projects under the same domain name.I jump to 5.2 after landing in 5.4, and the login status disappears,My cookie name is the same as the two project.

However, after my second attempt to land 5.4, I will not exit the login status after entering 5.2!why is this?

session_driver is redis

`'APP_KEY' is same`

### ps:

I want two laravel project share session

Comment: If you store the session in a database, you should ensure that both projects use the same database. Otherwise, you will start a session on project A and store that data in the database, but project B has no chance of reading that data...

Comment: My database configuration is the same！And the session can be Shared between the two projects after the second login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VBj0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIK92.png)

laravel 5.4 and 5.2 request resolution session method is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> I run two laravel projects under the same domain name

Are both projects in the same main folder ? If its that, you can't create 2 project in the same folder. You should have two different main folder with a sub-domain.

For the login status I recommend you to check [the Laravel upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade) which explain you how to migrate correctly your website to a new Laravel version.

You should use a database for sharing information between both website.

Comment: Is under two different main folder, website not migrate, but two separate functional modules, through different routing bound the same domain name, but the routing of two project is not the same